# Левой меню в Prestashop

Tags: javascript, prestashop

Доброе время суток, возник такой вопрос 
Есть стандартный модуль в Престашоп 1.7 для вывода меню всех категории на странице категории `ps_categorytree`, как добавить класс `active` до категории которая активная(тоесть там где находиться клиент).

К примеру - клиент находиться на категории Dresses и мне в меню надо к этой категории добавить класс `active` в левом меню.

Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому надо будет

В файл ps_categorytree.php ищем

```
return [
            'categories' => $this->getCategories($category),
            'currentCategory' => $category->id,
        ];
```

добавляем

```
return [
            'categories' => $this->getCategories($category),
            'currentCategory' => $category->id,
            'currentCategoryId' => Tools::getValue('id_category'),
        ];
```

в блок где надо добавить класс пишем

```
 <a {if isset($currentCategoryId) && $node.id == $currentCategoryId} class="category-sub-link selected"{else}class="category-sub-link"{/if} href="{$node.link}">{$node.name}</a>
```